# Remove ios App From Device also if removed from appstore sales

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have iOS app ready to sale on Apple Appstore. Now I have another app which i want all users to use instead of previous app. So I want to remove the earlier "ready for sale" from device also if I remove from sales section in AppStore. Can I do this?

Also our check for update code is not working in previously installed app and we dont want another update with same app, rather we want new app to be used. So is there any autoupdate from appstore even if user not updated manually

Regards,

Comment: No, you cannot remove an app from a user's device. Imagine if you could? I buy an app for $1.99 or $5.99 or $19.99, whatever, and suddenly it is no longer on my phone because the developer "remotely deleted" it!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a new app binary in the old AppStore application. It will be downloaded as an update for the previous app and completely replace it.

Comment: actually our check for update code is not working in previously installed app and we dont want another update with same app, rather we want new app to be used. So is there any autoupdate from appstore even if user not updated manually